Parted in scripted mode can increase but not decrease partition size
I am trying to use parted in scripted mode to resize a partition.
When I use the command to increase the partition size it works but when I use the same command but simply change the sector size to reduce the partition size it does not work.
If however I enter those details in interactive mode everything works fine whether increasing or decreasing the size of the partition.
I test with a .img file with one partition containing a btrfs file system. I loop mount the .img file to /dev/loop and partition 1 is at /dev/loop0p1. Partition 1 has an end sector at 48878656.
In the tests that follow I never try to increase the size of the partition beyond the maximum space available on the .img "disk" or below the size of the file system the partition contains.
Here I use parted in script mode to give information about the partition:
[flex@thinkpad ncp-pi]$ sudo parted -s -a opt /dev/loop0 "unit s print"
Model: Loopback device (loopback)
Disk /dev/loop0: 120933888s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End        Size       File system  Name  Flags
 1      2048s  48878656s  48876609s  btrfs

I use parted in scripted mode to INCREASE the size of the partition by increasing the position of the end sector from sector 48878656 to sector 49078656 and this works as expected:
[flex@thinkpad ncp-pi]$ sudo parted -s -a opt /dev/loop0 "unit s print resizepart 1 49078656 print"
Model: Loopback device (loopback)
Disk /dev/loop0: 120933888s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End        Size       File system  Name  Flags
 1      2048s  48878656s  48876609s  btrfs

Model: Loopback device (loopback)
Disk /dev/loop0: 120933888s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End        Size       File system  Name  Flags
 1      2048s  49078656s  49076609s  btrfs

Now using the same command I try to reduce the size of the partition by reducing the position of the end sector from sector 49078656 back to sector 48878656 however this does not work, the script wants me to answer 'Yes/No' even though I am in scripted mode?
[flex@thinkpad ncp-pi]$ sudo parted -s -a opt /dev/loop0 "unit s print resizepart 1 48878656 print"
Model: Loopback device (loopback)
Disk /dev/loop0: 120933888s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End        Size       File system  Name  Flags
 1      2048s  49078656s  49076609s  btrfs

Warning: Shrinking a partition can cause data loss, are you sure you want to continue?
[flex@thinkpad ncp-pi]$

I check the partition size again and nothing has changed, so that last command did not complete:
[flex@thinkpad ncp-pi]$ sudo parted -s -a opt /dev/loop0 "unit s print"
Model: Loopback device (loopback)
Disk /dev/loop0: 120933888s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End        Size       File system  Name  Flags
 1      2048s  49078656s  49076609s  btrfs

If instead I enter those details in interactive mode everything works fine.
There are some other questions on stackoverflow and other sites about parted in scripted mode. Functionality differs a little across distros and there may be a bug in it.
Other questions about parted in scripted mode:

How to use parted in script mode?
GNU parted resizepart in script
no way to use resizepart non-interactively on busy partition (Bug Report)

None of these sites have answered my question. How come my command to use parted in scripted mode can increase the size of the partition but not decrease it? How can I debug or find out what's going wrong?

Right after posting I see the problem is I thought my parted command was correctly suppressing parted prompts but it is not. Parted only gives the prompt Warning: Shrinking a partition can cause data loss... when shrinking but not when increasing a partition, that's why it only fails when trying to reduce the size of the partition. So I guess I can still use parted in script mode but need a different method to feed the parameters in and I have outlined one such method in my question above.

If parted was created with script focus in mind, it wouldn't even bother to ask you such questions. If you break your filesystem, that's your problem then. Unfortunately parted is primarily an interactive application, and script mode is somewhat of an afterthought. I don't think there is a solution (other than what you've already discovered). There's --fix which solves a similar problem but in a very narrow usecase. You could try and report it as a bug...

@frostschutz I'm using Parted 3.6 on Manjaro 24.0.2. I have tried lots of permutations of trying to feed 'yes' in to parted -s but it doesn't work. Looks like in my case I cannot use parted -s but instead use the ---pretend-input-tty hack or else sgdisk. On another thread you suggested to rm and mkpart the partition to the new size desired. Do you still suggest that? Surely that would delete all your data and also mkpart cannot specify a partition number so that would only work on a disk with one partition? What if you wanted to shrink partition 3 of 5 for example? I ask sincerely.

resizepart is nicer since it keeps the start sector, partition flags, partuuids etc. Re-creating the partition is an alternative if you can't make it work. Deleting a partition should not delete data; unless someone had the idea to implement trim/discard in parted, or wipe data on mkpart (LVM does such a wipe on lvcreate). If your partition numbers are not out of whack, mkpart would likely just pick the same one again. There's also a possible side effect; since parted performs all changes directly, the partition is really gone for a moment.

---pretend-input-tty was added in commit b235f8a4 and described "Support a new, undocumented option: ---pretend-input-tty. It is intended solely for testing." as such it might be dangerous to rely on it; on the other hand it has been around untouched since 2007 so... is breakage likely, who knows?

If you try to shrink a partition, with Parted running in script-mode, Parted issues the warning but then just exits out. This is because running in script mode by design Parted will not accept user input and it will NOT shrink a partition. Parted could give more informative feedback to the user in this scenario but that is how it is currently coded. I got confirmation from a Parted developer of this.
So in this case the problem was my incorrect understanding about how the Parted command is designed to function and also how to use the Parted command to do what I needed.
I have found several work-arounds, for instance these commands always work to increase and to decrease the size of the partition:
echo -e "resizepart 1 46280703s\nyes\nunit s\nprint\nquit" | sudo parted /dev/loop0 ---pretend-input-tty
sudo sgdisk -d 1 -n 1:2048:46378656 /dev/loop0

If you are willing to build your own bespoke version of Parted there is a very simple patch that will enable Parted, running in script-mode, to shrink a partition, as reported in this bug report.
--- a/parted/parted.c   2014-06-15 15:16:33.000000000 -0400
+++ b/parted/parted.c   2017-05-24 17:27:02.093371079 -0400
@@ -1551,7 +1551,7 @@ do_resizepart (PedDevice** dev, PedDisk*
                                           start, end))
                 goto error_destroy_constraint;
         /* warn when shrinking partition - might lose data */
-        if (part->geom.end < oldend)
+        if (part->geom.end < oldend && !opt_script_mode)
                 if (ped_exception_throw (
                             PED_EXCEPTION_WARNING,
                             PED_EXCEPTION_YES_NO,

